# rails 4 remote: true... submitting a form more than once

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

**view**

```
= form_tag foo_path, method: :get, class: 'form-inline', role: 'form', remote: true do
  .form-group
    = select_tag :year, options_for_select(@years, Date.today.year), class: 'form-control', prompt: 'Year'
  .form-group
    = select_tag :bar, options_for_select(@bars), prompt: 'Bar', class: 'form-control', disabled: true
  %br
  .form-group
    = submit_tag 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default'
```

**controller**

```
def foo
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

So I have a form, it's the first in a series of tabbed divs. You submit the form, a request is made, the form is hidden, and the next tab is shown, along with the ajax'd info from the form submission.

I want to allow the user to go back to the form and update it, if need be. My problem is, I can't seem to get the form to submit multiple times. I'm not sure it's a UJS issue, or a turbolinks issue (although I disabled turbolinks and still had the issue). I also am having to add that `render layout: false` bit, which I've never had to do in the past... This is rails 4.1.4.

I can see in the console, that the request is being made, and the approprate js is being rendered. (this is the actual response, not my fake foo example)

```
Started GET "/vehicles/query?utf8=%E2%9C%93&year=2014&mileage=&condition=&commit=Get+a+Quote" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-23 18:24:13 -0700
Processing by VehiclesController#query as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "year"=>"2014", "mileage"=>"", "condition"=>"", "commit"=>"Get a Quote"}
  Rendered vehicles/query.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Hey, the following is how I usually run my ajax forms, should work for you too. http://ericlondon.com/2014/01/25/ruby-on-rails-4-ajax-form.html

Comment: well, this works on the initial submit. i know how to use `$.ajax` but i feel like i shouldn't have to, here.

Comment: Try this? I can't seem to find any documentation on rails only handling requests on e though.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906966/need-to-allow-forms-to-be-resubmitted-rails-ajax

Comment: Try debugging it through the developer tools. js.erb templates don't show errors in the console by default, but open up the network tab, submit the form for the second time, click on the relevant request in the network tab, go to the response, and copy+paste it into the console and press enter, it may give you more information about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try disabling the submit button during the process, the rails way for doing this is:

```
submit_tag "Submit", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." }
```

Comment: that works... and is a cool feature, but it doesn't fix anything, unfortunately. i see it grey out and change initially, then when i go back to it, it's back to regular. clicking it again disables it for like 100ms then switches right back. no submit, though, after the first.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you'll have two potential issues:

> 1. Your Javascript will not be catching the next "submit"
> 2. If it *is* catching the submit, it won't be sending it

I would start looking at this by first ensuring my Javascript is catching the `submit` event on both occasions. This is evidently working for the first shot, but the next one does not:

--

**JS**

I would therefore remove the `remote: true` attribute, and try a manual ajax approach, binding to the `document` & delegating:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.rb
$(document).on("submit", "form-inline", function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: $(this).serialize();
      success: function(data) {
         // do something here
      };
   });
});
```

Because this is bound to the *document*, it should fire with impunity each time you perform a lookup. You'll want to read up on [javascript delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to see how this works

--

**Controller**

If your JS is getting through, perhaps the javascript is not firing on the other end.

If this is the case, you'll basically get it that you'll submit your request, but the controller will not perform any of the "backend" work that is required to get it working.

To fix this, I would move the backend `.js.erb` functionality into the `$.ajax({success:` function, so that it will definitely treat each request as individual, consequently allowing you to render it each time